# Firebase ads, only test ad

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads

I published an culture news app on Google Play Store, developed in Android Studio about a year ago. Few days ago I integrated firebase ads in this app the way this guy done it in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRT1Ho39MLU&t=5s

I published this update with ads included, but when I downloaded it from play store and start it, ad banner is there but all that shows is "nice job! you're displaying a 320x50 test ad from AdMob.

When I'll actually get real ads? Should I do something more?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using your actual `google-services.json`; you're using a test file provided by Firebase!

Download your project's *real* configuration [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en).

Comment: OK, i got my JSON, but what should I do with it now actually??

Comment: Replace the existing `google-services.json` in your project path with the file you downloaded. You'll find it at the root directory.

Comment: OK, I replaced it, build new version but when i test this version i still get nice job! you're displaying a 320x50 test ad from AdMob" in my banner

Comment: Actually, JSON that was in my project is 100% same as JSON i downloaded..... ?? any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111` as id it will shows like that change it with your unit id from admob, also

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign into your AdMob account.
2. Click on Monetize tab.
3. Select or Create the app and choose the platform.
4. Select the ad format either Banner or Interstitial and give the ad unit a name.And Creating more Banner ad unit id